# Using ipad camera connection kit on iPhone 4 through the SDK

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

I would like to develop an app which allows the users to copy their photos from their cameras to their iPhones. Since iOS 4.0 supports external accessories, theoretically this shouldn't be to hard, unless Apple specifically blocks it. I read the documentation for the ExternalAccessory.framework and ordered my camera connection kit.

While waiting for it to arrive, did anybody try to do something similar? Any success?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work using published APIs, unfortunately.  The External Accessory framework is just for use with specific devices that are in the Made for iPod program and that expose a protocol for third-party applications to use.  The Camera Connection Kit is not one of those devices.

There may be a way to get this to work using jailbroken iPhones, but I don't imagine it would be easy.

Comment: So, then I wouldn't be able to use the camera connection kit to do what I want not even on the iPad, right?

Comment: @Engin Kurutepe - The functionality for copying photos to the iPad is handled through the built-in Photos application.  While you may have access to the photos after they have been copied to the device, you have no means of directing that copy operation yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your response Brad, but I was planning to do some useful preprocessing for the photographers on the field before they get to their computers.

I found a piece of hardware that supposedly does what I need:
http://www.zoomitonline.com/
However it costs 60 bucks and I find it silly that Apple does not allow EAAccessory access to the camera connection kit. C'est la vie, i guess...

Comment: @Engin Kurutepe - Technically, they are not preventing you from accessing it, they just haven't provided an open External Accessory protocol for doing so, just like there isn't a protocol for a mess of other accessories.  I'm guessing the ZoomIt people have created their SD card reader as a Made for iPod device with a protocol for interacting with the cards.